# Is this depiction of a expression using only NAND gates correct?

Tags: boolean-logic

Original expression is here:

```
~xz+~yz
```

I simplified it to

```
~(x*y)*z
```

> Note: This is homework so an explanation/tips is appreciated.

**expression to NAND**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Correct, here is the logic, replacing NOT(foo and bar) with NAND(foo, bar)
Note in step 5, we get a NAND by applying NOT NOT to the expression in step 4

```
1. NOT X AND Z OR NOT Y AND Z
2. Z AND (NOT X OR NOT Y)  by Distributive property of AND
3. Z AND NOT (X AND Y)  by DeMorgan
4. Z AND NAND(X,Y)
5. NOT (NOT (Z AND NAND(X,Y)))
6. NOT NAND(Z, NAND(X,Y))
```